# How to perform dot in numpy without using inbuilt method?

Tags: python, numpy

I have following code which returns output : 4
Now I want to perform same operation without using dot() function. Is this possible?

```
import numpy as np

a=np.array([1,2])
b=np.array([2,1])
print(a.dot(b))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes It is possible, you can code like this :

```
import numpy as np

a=np.array([1,2])
b=np.array([2,1])
dot=0
for e,f in zip(a,b):
    dot+=e*f
print(dot)
```

Answer (score 0):

For Python 3.5 or higher

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([1,2])
b = np.array([2,1])

print(a @ b) # 4
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the dot product of two vectors is just the sum of their elementwise products, you can do this:

```
sum(a * b)
```

Don't use loops if you can avoid it; it's rarely called for in NumPy. If you really want to avoid NumPy altogether, a list comprehension is arguably more Pythonic:

```
sum(a_i * b_i for a_i, b_i in zip(a, b))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use Einstein summation form:

```
np.einsum('x,x->', a, b)
```